# Why is Oracle returning a Not Valid Month error

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

Can someone tell me why is this SQL query returning a

```
ORA-01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month"
```

I now it is wrong but it should be because 2018 is not a valid day. 09 is a valid month. I think..

```
select to_timestamp('2018-09-05 11:35:41', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mi:ss') from dual;
```

**I know that the query is wrong. I just want to know why it isn't saying `not a valid day` or something like that. the error is now saying that the month is wrong which is false.**

Comment: Hmmm, 2018 isn't a valid day of the month.  That seems pretty obvious.  The format needs to match your string.  It does seem strange that the error is about the month and not the day.

Comment: Your input string is `yyyy-mm-dd` but your format string is `dd/mm/yyyy` - apparently those don't match

Comment: Yes I agree. But the error says: NOT A VALID MONTH. It means that the month is false not the day part

Comment: I know my query is wrong but why is the error saying NOT A VALID MONTH. My month part is correct ( 09 ) it is the day part that is false

Comment: I know that the query is wrong. I just want to know why it isn't saying `not a valid day` or something like that. the error is now saying that the month is wrong which is false. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is because Oracle is trying to be clever/helpful.  So, it is interpreting:

```
select to_timestamp('2018-09-05 11:35:41', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mi:ss') from dual;
---------------------^ddMM
```

The `20` is interpreted as a valid day.  The month then follows. 
 Oracle is helpfully trying to ignore the separator.  Hence, the `18` is an invalid month.

Try this:

```
select to_timestamp('2012-2012', 'dd/MM/yyyy') from dual
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to understand. Didn't know Oracle interprets like this. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

If you "insist" to get an error message related to day then try the [FX](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#sthref418) modifier:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('2018-09-05 11:35:41', 'FXdd/MM/yyyy HH:mi:ss') FROM dual;

Error at line 1
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
```

I assume that is the error message you would expect.

Or try a "valid" month, e.g.

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('2008-09-05 11:35:41', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mi:ss') FROM dual;

Error at line 1
ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
```